# How to know when user clicks button inside notification

Tags: java, android

I have a Timer and I send a notification to the user when the timer finishes, I've added a "Stop" button to my notification and when the user clicks it I want the sound of the timer to stop.

What I tried is registering the action to my `BroadcastReceiver` in my `TimerActivity` like this:

```
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(TimerService.BROADCAST_ACTION);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

this is the BroadcastReceiver inside the `TimerActivity`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ScheduledService.STOP_TIMER))
            {
                if(timerAudio.isPlaying())
                {
                    timerAudio.stop();
                    timerAudio.release();
                    timerAudio = null;
                }
            } 
    };
```

And this is my how I create the notification inside the `ScheduledService` class:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CookingTimer.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(STOP_TIMER);
        PendingIntent stopTimer = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("This is a sample notification")
        .setContentText("Subject")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", stopTimer).build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

I've registered the `Service` and the action inside my Manifest and I receive the notification correctly, but the button action doesn't work.. Can someone explain me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Post the Activity that has the `MediaPlayer` controlling the sound.

If you are not receiving Null Pointer Exceptions, I suppose that `timerAudio` is correct.
However specify if the current view is defined and in context.